# SQL Server BULK insert - specify alternate row terminator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I am loading a text file in SQL Server 2008 R2 using the BULK Insert statement.

I use the following SQL:

```
declare @q varchar(MAX);
declare @csvfile varchar(100);

declare @csvpath varchar(200) = '\\path of folder'
declare @csvfullFileName varchar(200) = @csvpath+@csvfile+'.csv' 

set @q=
    'BULK INSERT #certs
    FROM '+char(39)+@csvfullFileName+char(39)+'
    WITH
    (

   FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
    FIRSTROW = 1  
    )'
exec(@q)
```

This all works fine when the file being loaded in has a CRLF as row terminators.

Occasionally, the file does not have LF and only has CR. This obviously causes a truncation error.

My question is, is it possible to have an alternate ROWTERMINATOR so regardless of CR or CRLF row termination, the file is still loaded?

Comment: If you know the format beforehand, you could use a format file. Or try with `\r` instead of `\n` if they always have a return but sometimes no line feed.

Comment: @JacobH \r does not work when the line is terminated with CRLF.. I get "An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file." error message.. might have to look into creating a format file and use BCP instead

Comment: I'd preprocess the file to have consistent row terminators, or fix the process that generates the file.

Comment: @TT. I agree.. but it's easier said than done.. especially when the file is from the Ministry /Government. Have you ever tried to get a large public organisation to change something or keep something consistent? ;)

Comment: @Harry As it happens I have :), it can be slow or it may never be fixed. In either case, copying the file, preprocessing it to have consistent CR/LF terminators and doing the import from there is doable. I don't think SQL Server is really suited for preprocessing, maybe powershell or some other environment.